# Getting single property from multiple views in couch db using ektorp

Tags: java, spring, collections, couchdb, ektorp

I am a beginner with couch db and ektorp. I want to use ektorp to retrieve one property from all the existing documents in couch db.

Till now I have learnt that couch db gives us the result of the following equivalent SQL query:-

```
Select * from Customer;
```

Is there any ektorp way of retrieving the result set of the following SQL query, Apart from the normal Map/reduce solutions of couch db?

```
Select name from customer;
```

The result set of the above query could somehow be retrieved in List or Set<> in java. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

if you only want one field returned from couchdb you must define a view that only contains that field.

however, it is generally best not to create that fine grained views. load the whole doc instead and transform the result in the application layer instead.

Comment: it would be nice if you accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Umm.. Actually I have somewhere around 3000-4000 records in my datatbase. All have a common document say employeeSalary. I want to fetch only distinct salaries of all employees from my db rather than fetching all records and fire a query that shall return me the same. Creating a separate view for the same doesn't seems apt either. Couldn't find a better way to do that. Will probably have look into something else. Thanks anyways.:)